# How many QTimers can I have in a pyqt app?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm working on a pyqt 5 app that controls a piece of industrial plant.
We have a lot of:
Do a for x seconds then do b for y minutes

Each of these is implemented with (mostly) single-shot QTimers. There are currently about 110 of these.
Most of these won't be running at the same time and timing accuracy is not critical at the sub-second level.

We now need to implement safety checks on top of this, for instance
If input c is too high for too long do something.

The list of these that came back from the ops team has 250+ conditions and will probably grow.
Sticking with how the code is currently written I'd implement each of these with another QTimer.

The code is set up with different objects for different parts of the system and the conditions will be read from a setup file, so implementing the safety system with lots of QTimers is doable, but is it a good idea?

Is having 300-400 QTimers in an app sensible? If it causes problems what will the symptons be?
Is there a different approach?
An answer from real world experience would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the demo I made based on musicamante's queue suggestion.
It adds the safety alerts to a queue and checks any that become due. Its light enough I hope to implement in the main control software

```py
from random import choice
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

HIGH = 1
OK = 0
LOW = -1
WATCH = 5
alert_colors = {
    HIGH: QColor("red"),
    OK: QColor("white"),
    LOW: QColor("lightblue"),
    WATCH: QColor("bisque"),
}

TIMER_INTERVAL = 500


def random_walk_int(start=0, offsets=[-1, 0, 1]):
    """
    generator to give integer value based on previous value
    """
    x = start
    while True:
        yield (x)
        dx = choice(offsets)
        x = x + dx


class ItemInput(object):
    def __init__(self, r, c, item):
        self.r = r
        self.c = c
        self.id = f"{r:03}{c:03}"
        self.item = item
        self.max = 55
        self.min = 45
        self.timeout = 5  # seconds
        self.gen = random_walk_int(start=50)

    def value(self):
        value = next(self.gen)
        self.item.setText(f"{value}")
        return value

    def alert_action(self, alert_type):
        self.item.setBackground(alert_colors[alert_type])


class CommonTimerTable(QTableWidget):
    accuracy = 0.1  # seconds

    def __init__(self, rows=50, cols=50):
        super().__init__(rows, cols)
        self.queue = {}
        self.inputs = {}
        self.rows = rows
        self.cols = cols
        for r in range(self.rows):
            for c in range(self.cols):
                item = QTableWidgetItem()
                self.setItem(r, c, item)
                input = ItemInput(r, c, item)
                self.inputs[input.id] = input

        self.resizeColumnsToContents()
        self.alert_queue = {}

        self.queueTimer = QTimer(interval=TIMER_INTERVAL, timeout=self.processQueue)
        self.queueTimer.start()

    def processQueue(self):
        # check all inputs and update alert_queue
        now = datetime.now()
        for key, input in self.inputs.items():
            value = input.value()
            if value > input.max:
                # if input not in alert_queue add it
                if key not in self.alert_queue:
                    self.alert_queue[key] = {
                        "due time": now + timedelta(seconds=input.timeout),
                        "input": input,
                        "alert type": HIGH,
                    }
                    input.alert_action(WATCH)
            elif value < input.min:
                # if input not in alert_queue add it
                if key not in self.alert_queue:
                    self.alert_queue[key] = {
                        "due time": now + timedelta(seconds=input.timeout),
                        "input": input,
                        "alert type": LOW,
                    }
                    input.alert_action(WATCH)
            else:
                # value is in bounds so if input in alert_queue remove it
                if key in self.alert_queue:
                    del self.alert_queue[key]
                    input.alert_action(OK)

        # action any due alerts
        for key, alert in self.alert_queue.items():
            if alert["due time"] < now:
                alert["input"].alert_action(alert["alert type"])


app = QApplication([])
w = CommonTimerTable(rows=50, cols=50)
w.showMaximized()
app.exec()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no real or absolute limit: it only depends on the capabilities of the CPU and how the whole process is implemented.

The following elementary example shows a QTableWidget with custom QTableWidgetItem subclasses, with each one of them having their own QTimer: when the timer expires, it updates its background color.

```py
from random import randrange
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class TimerItem(QTableWidgetItem):
    def __init__(self, text=''):
        super().__init__(text)
        self.timer = QTimer(singleShot=True, timeout=self.update)
        self.timer.start(randrange(500, 2500))

    def update(self):
        self.setBackground(QColor(
            randrange(255), randrange(255), randrange(255)
        ))
        self.timer.start(randrange(500, 2500))


class UniqueTimerTable(QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, rows=50, cols=50):
        super().__init__(rows, cols)
        for r in range(rows):
            for c in range(cols):
                self.setItem(r, c, TimerItem('{} {}'.format(r + 1, c + 1)))
        self.resizeColumnsToContents()


app = QApplication([])
w = UniqueTimerTable()
w.showMaximized()
app.exec()
```

With the above code, I can see a "low" average CPU usage (about 5%), even with my 12 year old computer and the window maximized... with 2500 items (and timers)!

Note that the "high" CPU usage is not uniquely related to the amount of timers, but most certainly *increased* by the Qt item view implementation and the usage of a higher level such as QTableWidget.

Still, there is always room for optimization.

You say that the accuracy is not critical and does not require sub-second precision, meaning that you can probably implement the whole process using a *single* timer.

The trick could be to use a "queue of events", based on a simple dictionary that "groups" elements by their timeouts:

- the keys are "common" accuracy-based timeouts: their items are lists containing the "timer objects" that finally call the timeout function;
- the unique timer calls a common update function, which checks each *sorted* key (timeout) of the queue, then:

  - if the key is below the given reference value, trigger the timeout function;
  - if it is not, update the key with the new timeout, decreased by the accuracy amount;
  - finally, add all previously "triggered" elements to the new timeout keys;

```py
class TimerObject(object):
    def __init__(self, item):
        self.item = item

    def timeout(self):
        self.item.setBackground(QColor(
            randrange(255), randrange(255), randrange(255)
        ))


class CommonTimerTable(QTableWidget):
    accuracy = .1
    def __init__(self, rows=50, cols=50):
        super().__init__(rows, cols)
        self.queue = {}
        for r in range(rows):
            for c in range(cols):
                item = QTableWidgetItem('{} {}'.format(r + 1, c + 1))
                self.setItem(r, c, item)

                timeout = randrange(1, 30) * self.accuracy
                if timeout in self.queue:
                    timerList = self.queue[timeout]
                else:
                    timerList = self.queue[timeout] = []
                timerList.append(TimerObject(item))
                
        self.resizeColumnsToContents()

        self.queueTimer = QTimer(interval=1000 * self.accuracy, 
            timeout=self.processQueue)
        self.queueTimer.start()

    def processQueue(self):
        renewed = []
        # sorting is mandatory!!!
        # it ensures that each new key is **always** below the previous value
        # while still preserving the sorted order of the timeouts (the keys)
        for timeout in sorted(self.queue.keys()):
            if timeout <= self.accuracy:
                objects = self.queue.pop(timeout)
                renewed.extend(objects)
                for timerObject in objects:
                    timerObject.timeout()
            else:
                self.queue[timeout - self.accuracy] = self.queue.pop(timeout)

        # note: this must be done *after* updating the timeouts, because new
        # objects have to be consistent with their *new* timeout
        for timerObject in renewed:
            timeout = randrange(1, 30) * self.accuracy
            if timeout in self.queue:
                timerList = self.queue[timeout]
            else:
                timerList = self.queue[timeout] = []
            timerList.append(timerObject)


app = QApplication([])
w = CommonTimerTable()
w.showMaximized()
app.exec()
```

With the above example, even with the same 2500 element count, the CPU usage is decreased to an average 3% even with a 100ms accuracy. If you are not interested in that level of precision, setting the `_accuracy` value to `.5` (half a second) results in less than 1% CPU usage even on my old machine.

Comment: I like the 2nd approach, both are very pretty. I've made a demo using a slightly different approach with the due times implemented with datetimes. This seems light enough on CPU with 0.5 second process loop.